# Obtener contenido html con inputs y sus valores escritos

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

me surge un inconveniente.

Estoy tratando de generar dinamicamente con un boton celdas de una tabla con `Inputs`.

Mi inconveniente, es que despues de haber llenado la primera fila y genero una mas me pone la que ya se habia llenado mas la nueva pero vacias:

Capturo el contenido `html()` y le agrego la nueva fila, mi codigo es asi:

este es el JS:

```js
    var numero = 0;
function crearfila(){
    //capturar el contenido de la tabla actual
    var contenidoTabla = $("#miBody").html();
    // var valores  = $("#miBody").text();
    // alert(valores);


    //obtener el valor de los campos requeridos
    var contenidoPlano = $("input[name='no_plano_"+numero+"']").val().length;
    var contenidoFecha = $("input[name='fecha_pl_"+numero+"']").val().length;
    //validar que no esten vacios
    if (contenidoPlano > 0 && contenidoFecha > 0) {
        var nuevaFila="";
        //se crea la nueva fila con los inputs adentro
        nuevaFila ="<tr class='gradeA'>";
        nuevaFila +=   "<th ><input size='14' name='no_plano_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='5' name='version_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='14' name='fecha_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='date' class='form-control datepicker'></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='32' name='descripcion_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input type='text' name='observacion_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila += "</tr>";

        //se envia en contenido mas la nueva fila
        $("#miBody").html(contenidoTabla+nuevaFila);
        //se aunmente la variable de factor de cambio
        numero = numero + 1;
    }else{
        //en caso de que el uno de los inputs este vacio
        alert('Falta rellenar algun campo');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="Jtabla" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" style="border-collapse:unset; " width="100%">
<thead style=" background-color: #9b9090; color: #fff;">
    <tr class="cabeza" >
        <th >No. Plano</th>
        <th >Version</th>
        <th >Fecha</th>
        <th >Descripcion</th> 
        <th >Observaciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="miBody">
    <tr class="gradeA">
       <th ><input size="14" name="no_plano_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input size="5" name="version_pl_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input size="14" name="fecha_pl_0" type="date" class="form-control datepicker"></th>
       <th ><input size="32" name="descripcion_pl_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input type="text" name="observacion_pl_0" class="form-control "></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="text-align: right;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="crearfila()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Espero me puedan colaborar, de antemano muchas gracias...
**NOTA:** he intentado con `text()` y  `val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas capturar el HTML.  Simplemente agrega la nueva fila con `append` asi:

```js
var numero = 0;
function crearfila(){    
    //obtener el valor de los campos requeridos
    var contenidoPlano = $("input[name='no_plano_"+numero+"']").val().length;
    var contenidoFecha = $("input[name='fecha_pl_"+numero+"']").val().length;
    //validar que no esten vacios
    if (contenidoPlano > 0 && contenidoFecha > 0) {
        var nuevaFila="";
        //se crea la nueva fila con los inputs adentro
        nuevaFila ="<tr class='gradeA'>";
        nuevaFila +=   "<th ><input size='14' name='no_plano_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='5' name='version_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='14' name='fecha_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='date' class='form-control datepicker'></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input size='32' name='descripcion_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' type='text' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila +=    "<th ><input type='text' name='observacion_pl_"+(numero+1)+"' class='form-control '></th>";
        nuevaFila += "</tr>";

        //se envia en contenido mas la nueva fila
        $("#miBody").append(nuevaFila);
        //se aunmente la variable de factor de cambio
        numero = numero + 1;
    }else{
        //en caso de que el uno de los inputs este vacio
        alert('Falta rellenar algun campo');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="Jtabla" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" style="border-collapse:unset; " width="100%">
<thead style=" background-color: #9b9090; color: #fff;">
    <tr class="cabeza" >
        <th >No. Plano</th>
        <th >Version</th>
        <th >Fecha</th>
        <th >Descripcion</th> 
        <th >Observaciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="miBody">
    <tr class="gradeA">
       <th ><input size="14" name="no_plano_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input size="5" name="version_pl_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input size="14" name="fecha_pl_0" type="date" class="form-control datepicker"></th>
       <th ><input size="32" name="descripcion_pl_0" type="text" class="form-control "></th>
       <th ><input type="text" name="observacion_pl_0" class="form-control "></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="text-align: right;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="crearfila()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: mestro ud como siempre tan preciso, muchas gracias...

Comment: quizas sepas una forma sencilla de capturar todos estos valores que he creado aqui ?

Comment: Quizas sea mejor que hagas otra pregunta.